# Split intervals longer than a threshold

Tags: python, split, intervals

I have a list of tuples, each defining an interval (start, end).
I would like to split the intervals which are longer than a certain threshold.

Example:

```
Initial list: segs = [(0,100),(120,140),(160,200)] 
Threshold: 30
```

Desired output:

```
split_segs = [(0,30),(30,60),(60,90),(90,100),(120,140),(160,190),(190,200)]
```

I come up with this code.

```
thr = 30.
split_segs = []
for a,b in segs:
    if b-a < thr:
        split_segs.extend([(a,b)])
    else:
        n = int((b-a)/thr)
        for i in range(n):
            if b-(a + (i+1)*thr) < thr:
                split_segs.extend([(a+(i+1)*thr, b)])
            else:
                split_segs.extend([(a+i*thr, a+(i+1)*thr)])
```

It works but looks very clumsy to me. Any better or more pythonic solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this slightly more elegantly by extending with a `range` that has a step of `threshold`:

```py
segs = [(0,100),(120,140),(160,200)]
threshold = 30
split_segs = []

for seg in segs:
    (a, b) = seg
    diff = b - a
    if diff <= threshold:
        split_segs.append(seg)
    else:
        split_segs.extend((n - threshold, n) for n in range(a + threshold, b + 1, threshold))
        if diff % threshold:
            # complete the gap
            split_segs.append((b - diff % threshold, b))

print(split_segs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this is a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution for your problem:

```
segs = [(0,100),(120,140),(160,200)] 
threshold = 30

def divide(to_divide):
    divided = []
    if to_divide[1] - to_divide[0] > threshold:
        divided.append((to_divide[0], to_divide[0] + threshold))
        divided.extend(divide((to_divide[0] + threshold, to_divide[1])))
        return divided
    else:
        return [to_divide]

divided = [el for x in segs for el in divide(x)]
print(divided)
```

The output will be:

```
[(0, 30), (30, 60), (60, 90), (90, 100), (120, 140), (160, 190), (190, 200)]
```

**UPDATE:** if you prefere a **non-recursive** solution, this is a possible one:

```
segs = [(0,100),(120,140),(160,200)] 
threshold = 30

def divide(to_divide):
    divided = []
    divided.extend((to_divide[0] + i * threshold, to_divide[0] + (i+1) * threshold) for i in range((to_divide[1] - to_divide[0]) // threshold))
    if divided:
        if divided[-1][1] != to_divide[1]:
            divided.append((divided[-1][1], to_divide[1]))
    else:
        divided.append((to_divide[0], to_divide[1]))
    
    return divided

divided = [el for x in segs for el in divide(x)]
print(divided)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice alternative. In general I preffer to avoid recursive code, but in this case is a nice option.

Comment: @Moz-stack Can I ask you why you want to avoid recursive code? It is fundamental in some contexts (not this of course) and can be really powerful. It can be complex but not to be avoided

Comment: In Python, recursion is slower than iterative code and can lead to running out of stack memory when inputs get large enough.

Comment: I am not saying to avoid recursive coding in general, but just when it doesn't provide a clear advantage. I think that iterative loops are more clear and easy to read. But this is just my personal opinion :)

Comment: Thanks @Aplet123, that was something that I had not considered (I would not demonise recursion anyway)

Comment: @Moz-stack I have updated the answer with a possible non recursive solution